# sonarqube msbuild runner NullPointerException

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

i'm trying to run SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild locally from command prompt and I receive always same error above no matter what project i build.
Sonar server  is remotly and reachable via web interface.

I'm building .NET(C#) projects, for .NET4.0 adn 4.5, I have .NET 4.5 to 4.6.2 installed locally.

Sonar server is version 6.1, because i'm just testing I'm using very basic configuration, internal DB used.

Error received during end phase (SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end)

any idea?

```
-----------
14:04:57.429 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
14:04:57.429 INFO: -------------------------------------------------------------
-----------
14:04:57.429 INFO: Total time: 5.475s
14:04:57.460 INFO: Final Memory: 41M/106M
14:04:57.460 INFO: -------------------------------------------------------------
-----------
14:04:57.460 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.sonar.plugins.csharp.sarif.SarifParser10.handleIssue(SarifParser1
0.java:69)
        at org.sonar.plugins.csharp.sarif.SarifParser10.handleIssues(SarifParser
10.java:56)
        at org.sonar.plugins.csharp.sarif.SarifParser10.parse(SarifParser10.java
:48)
        at org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpSensor.importRoslynReport(CSharpSensor
.java:291)
        at org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpSensor.analyse(CSharpSensor.java:113)
        at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecuto
r.java:57)
        at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java
:49)
        at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseE
xecutor.java:78)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanCon
tainer.java:182)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentC
ontainer.java:142)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer
.java:127)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer
.java:247)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectSc
anContainer.java:242)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectSc
anContainer.java:240)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanC
ontainer.java:232)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentC
ontainer.java:142)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer
.java:127)
        at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
        at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:
86)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentC
ontainer.java:142)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer
.java:127)
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContain
er.java:115)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:118)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.exec
ute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(Iso
latedLauncherProxy.java:60)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner
.java:233)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScann
er.java:151)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:110)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:74)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
14:04:57.460 ERROR:
14:04:57.476 ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full
debug logging.
Process returned exit code 1
The SonarQube Scanner did not complete successfully
14:04:57.492  Creating a summary markdown file...
14:04:57.492  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
```

Comment: i have tried with "sonar-scanner", now I have "EXECUTION SUCCESS" but I still would like to know why the MsBuild Scanner dont work... also I want the coverage from it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error with Version 6.1. After i changed my SonarQube Server to Version 5.6.3 i was able to analyze my project succesfully.

For testing: stop 6.1 server, unzip and start 5.6.3